# Shower enclosure leaking

Tags: shower

[image]I have water seeping around the shower and onto the floor. I removed the old caulking and resealed the inside and outside with a fast dry 30 minute sealer. 10 days later, it is still leaking and not sure what else to do.
Do we only seal the outside? or inside too? Some say only the outside and not the inside? What am I doing wrong? and what would be your recommendation . Thank you

**tried sending a picture but it will not upload

Comment: What sort of "sealer" are we talking about? It's often the case that the inside should not be caulked to allow proper drainage. I've seen cases where doing so resulted in leaks. My recommendation is to procure an installation manual for your product and follow it. There are no universal rules.

Comment: Thank you Isherwood, I just put a silicone base shower caulking and we will see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Check and make sure the leak is coming from the bottom sometimes water will run down the panels and the side collecting at the bottom. As for as sealer I always use bath and tub caulk it is designed for use in wet areas and resist mildew.  I use blue painters tape for a nice clean line and so I can work the caulk making sure I have a good bond remember to remove tape while the caulking is still wet.